# Use regex to find string between 1st and 2nd Comma in a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, substring

I have a string as:

```
"8/4/2022 9:47:59 AM,Gerald Digat Denys,8/4/2022 9:47:59 AM,Updated,207190091504228,CD_CODE_GD,CD_CODE_GD,CD_DESC_GDxxy,"
```

I want to extract the name between 1st and 2nd comma(,) as: `Gerald Digat Denys`

I tried the following way:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[^,a-z, A-Z,]+", String.Empty).Replace(",", "").Trim().ToString();
```

which is giving incorrect result as:

```
"AMGerald Digat Denys Ugas  AMUpdatedCDCODEGDCDCODEGDCDDESCGDxxy"
```

What Am I missing in regex? or How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `Split`. It's much cleaner, imo. `var result = myString.Split(',')[1];`

Comment: ^^ But also quite outdated since the dawn of `Span<char>` family of types.

Comment: ^^ => https://dotnetfiddle.net/fnKmbb